# assignment from incompatible pointer type struct c

Tags: c, struct, compiler-warnings

I am learning structs and pointers in C. I tried to make hashing function using table of nodes. I'm still getting warnings. I was looking for answer but I couldn't find it.

main:

```
int *T[N];
inittab(T);
chhinsert(T,206);
```

struct:

```
typedef struct{
  int key;
  struct node *next;    
}node;
```

function:

```
void chhinsert(int **T,int k){
  node *x=NULL;
  x=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  x->next=NULL;
  x->key=k;
  int p=h(k);
  //two lines below generates warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  x->next=T[p];
  T[p]=x;
}
```

I also tried

```
typedef struct node{...}node;
```

and then

```
void chhinsert(int **T,int k){
     struct node *x=NULL;
     x=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
     x->next=NULL;
     x->key=k;
     int p=h(k);
     x->next=T[p];
     T[p]=x;
}
```

every time I assign x to a value from table and vice versa warning shows

Comment: obviously they are not compatible struct node is not compatible with int *

Comment: `T[p]` is not a `struct node` is a double pointer to Integer. You cant assign it to a `x->next` which is a struct node.

Comment: Why would an `int` pointer hold the address of a `struct node`?

Comment: Please include the code of `inittab()`

Comment: `void inittab(int **T){
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
  T[i]=NULL;
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In line `void chhinsert(int **T,int k)` you declare `T` as a pointer to `int`, instead of a pointer to `node`. Change your declaration to `void chhinsert(struct node **T,int k)`.